# First Order differential equation ... How did they do it ?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, signal-processing

I was studying "continuous and discrete signals and systems" by Samir S. Soliman where I encountered with this first order differential equation:
$$
\frac{dy(t)}{dt} + \frac{R_1R_2}{L(R_1+R_2)}y(t) = \frac{R_2}{L(R_1+R_2)}x(t)
$$
 They mention that in next line " To compute an explicit expression for y(t) in terms of x(t), we must solve the differential equation for an arbitrary input x(t) applied for $\ t >= t_o $ . The complete solution is of the form "

$$
y(t) = y(t_o) exp[-\frac{R_1R_2}{L(R_1+R_2)}(t-t_o)] + \frac{R_2}{L(R_1+R_2)}\int_{t_o}^{t}exp[-\frac{R_1R_2}{L(R_1+R_2)}(t-\tau)]x(\tau) d\tau ;t >= t_o
$$

But there is no explanation how they get this result in detail. How did the solve this? How did they get this limit or$\ \tau $ . 
Please explain this total solution in detail (step by step  approach to solve this kind of problems is appreciated ) .

I have introductory knowledge on differential equation solving but never encountered this kind of problem.

Comment: This is called variation of parameters. There is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters) about it to get you started. And I have no doubt that searching for "variation of parameters" here will provide dozens of examples, and explanations.

Comment: $\tau$ is just a dummy variable for the integral.  It takes the place of $t$ since the integral limits involve $t$.  Another common choice of integration variable is $s$.

Comment: Thnx.. I got the basic idea. But can't figure out where they get $\(t-t_o) $ in first place . shouldn't it be only t ?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegratingFactor.html A far simpler method than variation of parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### General Solution (using the method of integrating factor):

Let $\alpha = \frac{R_1R_2}{L(R_1+R_2)}$ and $\beta=\frac{R_2}{L(R_1+R_2)}$. The linear inhomogeneous differential equation becomes:

$$\frac{dy(t)}{dt}+\alpha y(t) = \beta x(t)$$

Let $\mu(t)  =  e^{\int \alpha dt}  =  e^{\alpha t}$ and multiply both sides by $\mu(t)$:
$$e^{\alpha t} \frac{dy(t)}{dt}+\alpha e^{\alpha t} y(t)  =  \beta e^{\alpha t} x(t)$$

Substitute $\alpha e^{\alpha t}  =  \frac{d}{dt}(e^{\alpha t})$:
$$e^{\alpha t} \frac{dy(t)}{dt}+\frac{d}{dt}(e^{\alpha t}) y(t)  =  \beta e^{\alpha t} x(t)$$
Apply the reverse product rule $g \frac{df}{dt}+f \frac{dg}{dt}  =  \frac{d}{dt}(f g)$ to the left-hand side:
$$\frac{d}{dt}(e^{\alpha t} y(t))  =  \beta e^{\alpha t} x(t)$$
Integrate both sides with respect to $t$:
$$\int \frac{d}{dt}(e^{\alpha t} y(t)) dt  =  \int \beta e^{\alpha t} x(t) dt$$
Evaluate the integrals:
$$e^{\alpha t} y(t)  =  \beta  \int e^{\alpha t} x(t) dt+C$$ where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

Divide both sides by $\mu(t)  =  e^{\alpha t}$ to get the general solution:
$$y(t)  =  \beta e^{-\alpha t}  \int e^{\alpha t} x(t) dt+C e^{-\alpha t}$$

---

I will leave the rest for you. Give it a shot.